# How to implement a simple scenario the OO way

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns

After starting to read a book on OO programming, I am attempting to make my android app more OO. However I am stumped on a simple scenario.

I have a `Book` object, which can have many say `Chapter` objects. I also have a search function which searches across multiple books, 97 of them. I end up with many Chapter objects from the Sqlite table.

I felt that it would be useful to the user to be able to see the title of the book on each result, otherwise it might be confusing if there are say two "chapter 5" results.

For that to happen, I need the book title. Should I make it part of my chapter object, like :

```
chapter.getBookTitle()
```

Which kind of does not seem right, as I have glued the book name onto a chapter... The alternative is to instantiate a book object for each chapter and somehow reference it, which has its own problems including in android with regards to not being able to pass a reference to an in-memory object to another activity.

Also a book may have many other chapters which were not results in the search, and it may seem like they would return if I was to just instantiate the book.

What is the correct OO solution to this seemingly simple issue? Is it just a matter of learning when not to be dogmatic about the whole OO thing?

**More Info:**

I am using FTS4 in Sqlite, which accounts for over half of my actual DB size of 80mb. What I am storing is text from 97 books, with chapters in 4 languages. So my FTS at the moment stores:

```
ChapterId, ChapterNo (withinBook), Lang1, Lang2, Lang3, Lang4, Tags, Notes
```

The searching is very fast, I retrieve only 50 results. I match any column with a string term, and not one column in particular. So if I type "apple" it will search all the fields above.

Currently as part of my FTS query I am join a join onto Book, fetching the BookId, I later use that to get me the title of the book. However its all in a procedural like style, with no regard to where the information "belongs".

I need the title so I can display it in the results, just for user convenience.

It works well, however I am wanting similar performance or slightly less but with an OO approach as I think that will make more sense to me when I come back to this project after a long pause.

Comment: While `bookTitle` doesn't really fit a `Chapter` class, having a property name `book` saying what book it belongs to would be fine imo.  Yes, there isn't really a difference between the two properties, but the second one makes more OO sense imo.

Comment: Two way references aren't always a bad thing

Comment: @RichardTingle for me two way references can be a bad thing, if Chapter refs Book, then Book refs its chapters it means wanting a single chapter could create refs to the other 1000 sibling chapters indirectly, meaning they have to be loaded, take up memory etc. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: All depends how you're storing your data. If its being loaded from disk yes that mighy happen. But if it's all loaded in RAM as in a normal program (as it sounds like from your description) then it doesn't matter. You haven't mentioned if you're using a database or just collections which may make a difference

Answer (score 2):

The Chapter object should have reference to the book it came from so I would suggest something like 
`chapter.getBook().getTitle();`

Your database table structure should have a books table and a chapters table with columns like:

books

- id
- book specific info
- etc

chapters

- id
- book_id
- chapter specific info
- etc

Then to reduce the number of queries use a join table in your search query.

Comment: Yep that is how my db schema is.

Comment: I would like to add that since I am using an FTS search to get my current results, having `chapter.getBook().getTitle();` will cause me to run another query for each search item found.

Comment: What are you using for FTS that will not allow you to join the books table to the chapters found?

Comment: Adding a bookid into the FTS would be easy enough. But to instantiate the whole book would need a separate query off that id

Comment: Please explain more about your search. How/Where is your data stored? How are you currently doing your full text search?

Comment: Someone correct me if I am wrong but with FTS4 and sqlite you should be able to join the books table in your query with something like: SELECT * FROM chapters JOIN books ON chapters.book_id = books.id WHERE ...   Then using the resulting cursor get the books title value as it will be include in the cursors table.

Comment: Yes you can do that, and I am. Which is what led to this question, its very efficient for me to just get the book title and include it with the chapter, so that is why I mentioned that it was not OO to have the title with the chapter. There are two alternatives, 1) get the book id, instantiate the book, and attach it to the chapter, or 2) get all of the book fields in the FTS query by a join and instantiate using them instead of of a new query, however this does not feel right, and the the first approach is slow... which brings me back to why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take is: when reading the chapters from the database, instead of a collection of chapters, use a collection of books. This will have your chapters organised into books and you'll be able to use information from both classes to present the information to the user (you can even present it in a hierarchical way easily when using this approach).

Comment: This would lead me to have references to chapters in the Book object, how would I tell it which chapters I want included as there could be a 1000? I cannot load all of them as it would lead to massive amounts of data...

Answer (score 0):

You might implement your class model by composition, having the book object have a map of chapter objects contained within it (map chapter number to chapter object). Your search function could be given a list of books into which to search by asking each book to search its chapters. The book object would then iterate over each chapter, invoking the chapter.search() function to look for the desired key and return some kind of index into the chapter. The book's search() would then return some data type which could combine a reference to the book and some way to reference the data that it found for the search. The reference to the book could be used to get the name of the book object that is associated with the collection of chapter search hits.

Comment: This would lead to a lot of db queries no? My current method uses a FTS search so its very simple and easy, having each book search its chapters would need 97 such queries.

Comment: Well, I wasn't trying to address any DB issues, I had keyed in to your question about how to OO represent this.